# sql combine two columns that might have null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

This should be an easy thing to do but I seem to keep getting an extra space. Basically what I am trying to do is combine multiple columns into one column. BUT every single one of these columns might be null as well. When I combine them, I also want them to be separated by a space (' ').

What I created is the following query:

```
select 'All'= ISNULL(Name+' ','')+ISNULL(City+' ','')+ISNULL(CAST(Age as varchar(50))+' ','')  from zPerson
```

and the result is:

```
All
John Rock Hill 23 
 Munchen 29 
Julie London 35 
 Fort Mill 27 
Bob  29
```

As you can see: there is an extra space when the name is null. I don't want that.

The initial table is :

```
id  Name    City            Age InStates    AllCombined
1   John    Rock Hill       23  1              NULL
2           Munchen         29  0              NULL
3   Julie   London          35  0              NULL
4           Fort Mill       27  1              NULL
5   Bob                     29  1              NULL
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which DBMS..............??

Comment: i Guess its sql server..

Comment: This sounds like a case for the generous application of `COALESCE()` and `NULLIF()`

Comment: COALESCE and isnull have the same result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 'All'= LTRIM(ISNULL(Name+' ','')+ISNULL(City+' ','')+ISNULL(CAST(Age as varchar(50))+' ','')  from zPerson)
```

[SEE LTRIM()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177827%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: That doesn't help him for the final row, which gives `Bob__27` (with 2 spaces)

Comment: RB you are correct.. but his solution gave me the idea to use ltrim for every single field.. so his solution is the one that solved the problem: the final query that i used is : 

select 'All'= ltrim(isnull(Name+' ',''))+ltrim(isnull(City+' ',''))+ltrim(isnull(CAST(Age as varchar(50))+' ',''))  from zPerson

Comment: @RB Yes you are right.. but OP only wants to remove first extra spaces that's i suggested this to him..

Comment: @Pranav Re-reading the question I agree you're right - you did answer the OPs query, so +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

In the data you have posted, the `Name` column contains no NULLs. Instead, it contains empty strings, so `ISNULL(Name+' ','')` will evalate to a single space.

The simplest resolution is to change the data so that empty-strings are null. This is appropriate in your case since this is clearly your intention.

```
UPDATE zPerson SET Name=NULL WHERE Name=''
```

Repeat this for your `City` and `Age` fields if necessary.

Comment: +1 for a solution that works around the problem and it's done in 2 steps. This would be a good solution but my tables haveover 1 million records...but Pranav's solution is right on the spot

Comment: Out of interest, why does the fact that you have a million records prevent this being a good solution? Also note that this is not a workaround - it is the correct answer! If you do not know someone's name you should store it as NULL, as otherwise you are claiming that their name is an empty-string - databases are all about semantics :)

Comment: the data comes daily from different sources some as null, some as empty strings... We are talking about millions of records daily with over 40 fields each, so im sorry for not giving more details...

Comment: Well, if you've decided it's not the right approach for pragmatic reasons, that's fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [TRIM()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) arount the ISNULL() function, or [LTRIM()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) around the entire selected term

Comment: That would be no good for him. `TRIM(ISNULL(Name + ' ', ''))` would remove the spaces he had so carefully added!